# Using custom Loopback user model with loopback-component-passport

Tags: facebook, express, loopbackjs, passport.js

I'm trying to use a extended loopback user model together with the loopback-component-passport for facebook login. The login itself is working but i can't get it to use my custom user model instead of the builtin "Users".

steps i took:

**- create custom user model with slc loopback:model extending "User"**

```
{
  "name": "myuser",
  "plural": "myusers",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "mytestproperty": {
      "type": "string",
      "default": "myteststring"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

**- Setup passport component with the new user model:**

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  var passportConfigurator = new PassportConfigurator(app);

  passportConfigurator.init();
  passportConfigurator.setupModels({
    userModel: app.models.myuser,
    userIdentityModel: app.models.UserIdentity,
    userCredentialModel: app.models.UserCredential
  });
  passportConfigurator.configureProvider('facebook-login',
    require('../../providers.json')['facebook-login']);
};
```

**Problem:**
When i log in with via facebook the passport component still uses the "Users" model as seen in my db.json storage:

```
{
  "ids": {
    "User": 2,
    "UserCredential": 1,
    "UserIdentity": 2,
    "AccessToken": 2,
    "ACL": 1,
    "RoleMapping": 1,
    "Role": 1,
    "myuser": 1
  },
  "models": {
    "User": {
      "1": "{\"username\":\"facebook.13371337\",\"password\":\"blablabla\",\"email\":\"blablabla\",\"id\":1}"
    },
    "UserCredential": {},
    "UserIdentity": {
      "1": "{\"provider\":\"ALL MY IDENTITY INFO BLABLABLA}"
    },
    "AccessToken": {
      "1337": "{\"id\":\"1337\",\"ttl\":1209600,\"created\":\"2017-03-01T09:34:51.965Z\",\"userId\":1}"
    },
    "ACL": {},
    "RoleMapping": {},
    "Role": {},
    "myuser": {}
  }
}
```

As you can see "Users" is populated with my newly created user and "myuser" is empty.

Am i mistaking something or what is the correct way to extend the loopback user together with passport?
Any tips or references to a example are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to extend all passport related models, so you can have them linked to your custom user model.

*user.json*

```
{
  "name": "user",
  "plural": "users",
  "base": "User",
  "relations": {
    "accessTokens": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "accessToken",
      "foreignKey": "userId"
    },
    "identities": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "userIdentity",
      "foreignKey": "userId"
    },
    "credentials": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "userCredential",
      "foreignKey": "userId"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

*user-identity.json*

```
{
  "name": "userIdentity",
  "plural": "userIdentities",
  "base": "UserIdentity",
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "user": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "user",
      "foreignKey": "userId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

*user-credential.json*

```
{
  "name": "userCredential",
  "plural": "userCredentials",
  "base": "UserCredential",
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "user": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "user",
      "foreignKey": "userId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

*access-token.json*

```
{
  "name": "accessToken",
  "plural": "accessTokens",
  "base": "AccessToken",
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "user": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "user",
      "foreignKey": "userId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

*server.js (relevant part)*

```
const PassportConfigurator = require('loopback-component-passport').PassportConfigurator
const passportConfigurator = new PassportConfigurator(app)

let providersConfig = require('./providers.json')

passportConfigurator.init()

passportConfigurator.setupModels({
  userModel: app.models.user,
  userIdentityModel: app.models.userIdentity,
  userCredentialModel: app.models.userCredential
})

for (let s in providersConfig) { // Configure providers based on providers.json config
  let c = providersConfig[s]
  c.session = c.session !== false
  passportConfigurator.configureProvider(s, c)
}
```

There is also [an example repository](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-passport), which might be useful for you.

Comment: Thank a lot! I was already questioning my sanity :D 
But to be honest the whole user extending thing in loopback is suboptimal...

Comment: I agree with that. It also took me a while. Although looking on their release notes they are gradually improving these things. Let's hope it will get better.